# ZF2 XML Creation

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to zend framework 2 . Can any one describe me how to create XML files using ZF2 .
I need to access remote server via sending data through XML file . So I need to create a xml file with lot of sub divisions by creating and appending XML file . Please somebody describe me how to do it . Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=create+xml+files+using+zend&oq=create+xml+files+using+zend#q=create+xml+files+using+zf2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use php xml functions

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$elm = $doc->createElement("NCScript");
$elm->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://yourpath:NStd');
$elm->setAttribute('xmlns:NStd', 'http://yourpath');
$elm->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://yourpath');
$doc->appendChild($elm);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $b = $doc->createElement("Auth");
$partnerName = $doc->createElement("partnerName");
$partnerName->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode('Partnername')
);
$b->appendChild($partnerName);

$name = $doc->createElement("name");
$name->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode('username')
);
```

use this we can create xml file and use `$xml = $doc->saveXML();` to return the xml file